# I'm getting this when doing a test: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, laravel, function, testing

I'm getting this error when executing a test and I don't know how to solve this issue, any ideas?

> 1) Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth\Editar_Pelicula::Editar_Pelicula
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Function name must be a string

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;
use App\Movie;

class Editar_Pelicula extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    /** @test */
    public function Editar_Pelicula(){
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->withoutMiddleware()->put('catalog/edit/1', [
            'title' => 'testeo',
            'year' => '9999',
            'director' => 'Eduard',
            'synopsis' => 'blablabla',
            'category' => 3,
            'trailer' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX'
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('movies', [
            'title' => 'testeo',
            'year' => '9999',
            'director' => 'Eduard',
            'synopsis' => 'hola',
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use underscore in a method name, can you replace **Editar_Pelicula** by **EditarPelicula** ?

Comment: I tried it but it still shows the sameerror message

Comment: Since your class and method are both named `Editar_Pelicula`, the method acts as a constructor for the class. This likely overrides the construction the framework needs to do. I would suggest you rename the _method_ to `testEditarPelicula` -- this will make it a regular instance method and, being named `test` clues the framework into the fact that it's a test scenario.

Comment: @bishop you should probably post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class and method are both named `Editar_Pelicula`, the method acts as a constructor for the class. This isn't what you want to do.

To signal that the method is a test scenario, rename the method so that it begins with `test`. Then, best practice is to name the method in a way that describes the scenario being tested.

For example, rename the method to `test_A_Valid_Put_Changes_Database`.